# Installed FIFA 11: Runs without gamepad, crashes with it

Tags: wine, 17.10

**SYSTEM:** Ubuntu 17.10
**RAM:** 8GB
**Intel I5**

I installed FIFA 11 for wine and it worked perfectly fine with keyboard. (Note that I already installed Direct X, .NET framework and other stuff.)

After I quit the application, and try running it again with the gamepad plugged in again, it crashes after showing me the FIFA 11 Splash Screen.

Here's my `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3a6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0079:0006 DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

What's wrong? How can I fix the game so that I can use my gamepad to play it? If I need to run any other commands, let me know in the comments.

Terminal Output onCrash:

```
$ ./fifa11.sh 
0019:fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000380, 00000000): partial stub.
0036:err:hid_report:process_hid_report Device reports coming in too fast, last report not read yet!
0036:err:hid_report:process_hid_report Device reports coming in too fast, last report not read yet!
------------------------------------------------------------
Total user memory:      2048.00 MB - 2147483647 bytes
Total available memory: 2048.00 MB - 2147483647 bytes
------------------------------------------------------------
arg0: fifa.exe
loading: C:\Program Files\EA Sports\FIFA 11\Game\memoryfw.ini
Using Use embeded copy of file C:\Program Files\EA Sports\FIFA 11\Game\memoryfw.ini
MemoryTracking heap disabled!
Memory Initialization over
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Memory before heap allocation:            2048.00 megs - 2147483647 bytes
Memory available after heap allocation    2048.00 megs - 2147483647 bytes
Total memory used by heaps:               0.00 megs - 0 bytes

Creating EA::Messaging::Server
Initializing EA Messaging system
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0xcc): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x2d0): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x2d4): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x2d8): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x2dc): stub
Preloading 1st big file
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x2e0): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x2e4): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x2e8): stub
~~~~~~~~~~~done preload
loading locale big file
~~~~~~~~~~~done loading locale big file
0009:fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unimplemented action: 59 (SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS)
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x304): stub
Changelist # for this build: 7360630009:fixme:d3d:init_driver_info Unhandled OS version 6.3, reporting Win 8.
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x1a2ed74,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x310): stub
Before LoadDataArchives(1)
After LoadDataArchives(1)
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7acca82c, 0x1d45c9e8, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7acca82c
0009:fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7acca82c, 0x75df6680, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7acca82c
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7acca82c, 0x75df78c8, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7acca82c
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7acca82c, 0x75df7878, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7acca82c
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0x7acca82c, 0x75dfd5c8, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
0009:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0x7acca82c
Pads 3 out of 3
Device 0: 6->6: PAD
Device 1: 7->7: PAD
Device 2: 5->5: KEYBOARDPAD
Device 3: 4->4: MOUSE
Device 4: 5->5: KEYBOARD
C:\users\abhishek\My Documents\FIFA 11\buttonDataSetup.ini : size 96992, pointer 037478B0
0009:fixme:dsound:DSOUND_RecalcFormat Conversion from 8 to 2 channels is not implemented, falling back to stereo
0009:fixme:dsound:DSOUND_RecalcFormat Conversion from 8 to 2 channels is not implemented, falling back to stereo
0009:fixme:dsound:DSOUND_RecalcFormat Conversion from 8 to 2 channels is not implemented, falling back to stereo
0009:fixme:dsound:DSOUND_RecalcFormat Conversion from 8 to 2 channels is not implemented, falling back to stereo
0009:fixme:dsound:DSOUND_RecalcFormat Conversion from 8 to 2 channels is not implemented, falling back to stereo
0009:fixme:dsound:DSOUND_RecalcFormat Conversion from 8 to 2 channels is not implemented, falling back to stereo
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x34c): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x35c): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x3a8): stub
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x3ac): stub
RenderThread started
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x3b0): stub
FEThread started
InputThread started
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x3c0): stub
Mounting data/sceneassets/genheadtex.big
0009:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x3c4): stub
DLC Event received: INITIALIZATION_COMPLETE
004a:fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x3e4): stub
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x8bf18bba at address 0xefdc16 (thread 004b), starting debugger...
0019:fixme:service:QueryServiceConfig2W Level 6 not implemented
0056:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {5c6fb596-4828-4ed5-b9dd-293dad736fb5}
0056:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0056:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {5c6fb596-4828-4ed5-b9dd-293dad736fb5}, 80004002
005b:err:rpc:I_RpcReceive we got fault packet with status 0x80004002
0019:fixme:ole:NdrClearOutParameters (0x87e3dc,0x7e807120,0x87e564): stub
0056:err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
0019:err:ole:ifproxy_release_public_refs IRemUnknown_RemRelease failed with error 0x800706be
0019:fixme:ole:CoCreateInstanceEx no instance created for interface {5c6fb596-4828-4ed5-b9dd-293dad736fb5} of class {09934fb3-22e3-4e82-b534-0a98f89a9e48}, hres is 0x80004002
0019:fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L".NET Runtime Optimization Service"): stub
0019:fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0001,0x0000,0x00000456,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x87f6fc,(nil)): stub
0019:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L".NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32) - Service Manager returned a fatal error (0x80004002). Will stop service\n"
0019:fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
0019:fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L".NET Runtime Optimization Service"): stub
0019:fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
^CCtrl-C: stopping debuggee
0061:fixme:console:CONSOLE_DefaultHandler Terminating process 51 on event 0
```

Comment: If you launch the game from Terminal, what's the output when it crashes?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine I have added the terminal output to the question. Can you see what's going wrong?